# Adding and deleting input fields on click of a button in a form in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Please run the below code.

i am a beginner in coding.

I am making a form which contains various fields.

As you can see that in the Education field on click of add education button I am successfully able to add another education field but I am not able to delete the exact field. Please help!

Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Assignment</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Candidate Information</h1>
    <h2>Submit Your Info</h2>
    <form>

        <!-- name -->
        <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" required><br />

        <!-- gender -->
        <br/><label for="gender"><b>Gender</b></label><br/>
        <br/><label for="male"> Male</label>
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" />
        <label for="female"> Female</label>
        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female" /><br />

        <!-- address -->
        <br /><label for="address"><b>Address</b></label>
        <br /><textarea rows="6" name="address" cols="70" placeholder="Enter your address" maxlength="200" required></textarea><br />

        <!-- email -->
        <br/><label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" title="Please enter the correct email" required><br />

        <!-- phone -->
        <br/><label for="phone"><b>Phone</b></label>
        <input type="tel" placeholder="Enter your phone number" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="Phone number can only be 10 digits" required><br /><br />

        <!-- education -->
        <p><b>Education</b></p>
        <div id="education">
            <label for="level"><b>Level:</b></label>
            <select name="level" id="level">
                <option>-Please select a level-</option>
                <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
                <option value="HSSC">HSSC</option>
                <option value="Diploma">Diploma</option>
                <option value="BE">BE</option>
                <option value="BTech">BTech</option>
                <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
                <option value="MCA">MCA</option>
            </select>
            <label for="year"><b>Year</b></label>
            <input type="number" name="year1" max="2020" min="2000" />
            <label for="grade"><b>Grade/%</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="grade1" />

        </div>
        <input name="addeducation" type="button" value="Add Education" onClick="addEducation('education');"><br/><br/>

        <script>
            var counter = 1;
            var limit = 4;
            function addEducation(divname) {

                if (counter == limit) {
                    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
                }
                else {
                    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                    newdiv.className='addeduclass'+counter;
                    newdiv.innerHTML = "<label><b>Level: </b><label/>" + "<select><option>-Please select a level-</option><option value='SSC'>SSC</option><option value='HSSC'>HSSC</option><option value='Diploma'>Diploma</option><option value='BE'>BE</option><option value='BTech'>BTech</option><option value='BCA'>BCA</option><option value='MCA'>MCA</option></select>" +
                        "<label><b>  Year</b><label/> " + "<input type='number' name='year' max='2020' min='2000'/>" +
                        "<label><b>Grade/%</b><label/> " + "<input type='text' name='grade'/>"+
                        "<button type='button' onClick='removeEducation('education',newdiv.className)'>Remove</button>";
                    document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(newdiv);
                    counter++;
                    console.log(counter);
                    console.log(newdiv.className);
                }
            }


            function removeEducation(edudiv,divname) {
                console.log("deleted");
                document.getElementsByClassName(edudiv).removeChild(divname);
                counter--;
            }
        </script>

        <!-- skills -->
        <p><b>Skills</b></p>
        <div id="skills">
            <label for="skillname"><b>Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="skillname">
            <label for="rating"><b>Rating:</b></label>
            <select name="rating" id="rating">
                <option>-Please select a rating-</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input name="addskill" type="button" value="Add Skill" onClick="addSkill('skills');"><br/>

        <script>

            var skillcounter = 1;
            var skilllimit = 3;
            function addSkill(divname1) {

                if (skillcounter == skilllimit) {
                    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + skillcounter + " inputs");
                }
                else {
                    var snewdiv = document.createElement('div');
                    snewdiv.className="addskillclass"
                    snewdiv.innerHTML = "<label><b>Name</b></label>" + "<input type='text' name='skillname1'/>"+
                    "<label><b>Rating:</b></label>" + "<select><option>-Please select a rating-</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='6'>6</option><option value='7'>7</option><option value='8'>8</option><option value='9'>9</option><option value='10'>10</option></select>";
                    document.getElementById(divname1).append(snewdiv);
                    skillcounter++;
                    console.log(counter);
                }
            }


            // function removeSkill(divname1) {

            // }
        </script>

        <!-- hobby -->
        <br/>
        <label for="hobby"><b>Hobby</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your hobby" name="hobby"><br /><br />

        <!-- photourl -->
        <label for="photourl"><b>Photo</b></label>
        <input type="url" name="photourl" placeholder="photo url" /><br />

        <!-- submit -->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think there is an error in your innerHTML `...onClick='removeEducation('education',newdiv.className)'>...`. You have single quotes enclosed in single quotes. Try chaning it to `onClick='removeEducation(\"education\",newdiv.className)'>`

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify this a little like so:
Pass the delete button into the function `removeEducation` using the keyword `this`, so change to the following on your delete education buttons:

```
onClick='removeEducation(this);'
```

Then in your `removeEduction` function, you pass in the delete button which is clicked, traverse it to the parent node of the parent div of the button and then use `removeChild` to remove the parent div of the delete button:

```
 function removeEducation(deleteButton) {
      deleteButton.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(deleteButton.parentNode);
      counter--;
 }
```

Just a small piece of advice, it is recommended to add event handling to elements via `javascript` using `.addEventListener` instead of `inline` in the `html` You can read more about that here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Assignment</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Candidate Information</h1>
    <h2>Submit Your Info</h2>
    <form>

        <!-- name -->
        <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" name="name" required><br />

        <!-- gender -->
        <br/><label for="gender"><b>Gender</b></label><br/>
        <br/><label for="male"> Male</label>
        <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male" />
        <label for="female"> Female</label>
        <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female" /><br />

        <!-- address -->
        <br /><label for="address"><b>Address</b></label>
        <br /><textarea rows="6" name="address" cols="70" placeholder="Enter your address" maxlength="200" required></textarea><br />

        <!-- email -->
        <br/><label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
        <input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" name="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" title="Please enter the correct email" required><br />

        <!-- phone -->
        <br/><label for="phone"><b>Phone</b></label>
        <input type="tel" placeholder="Enter your phone number" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{10}" title="Phone number can only be 10 digits" required><br /><br />

        <!-- education -->
        <p><b>Education</b></p>
        <div id="education">
            <label for="level"><b>Level:</b></label>
            <select name="level" id="level">
                <option>-Please select a level-</option>
                <option value="SSC">SSC</option>
                <option value="HSSC">HSSC</option>
                <option value="Diploma">Diploma</option>
                <option value="BE">BE</option>
                <option value="BTech">BTech</option>
                <option value="BCA">BCA</option>
                <option value="MCA">MCA</option>
            </select>
            <label for="year"><b>Year</b></label>
            <input type="number" name="year1" max="2020" min="2000" />
            <label for="grade"><b>Grade/%</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="grade1" />

        </div>
        <input name="addeducation" type="button" value="Add Education" onClick="addEducation('education');"><br/><br/>

        <script>
            var counter = 1;
            var limit = 4;
            function addEducation(divname) {

                if (counter == limit) {
                    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
                }
                else {
                    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
                    newdiv.className='addeduclass'+counter;
                    newdiv.innerHTML = `<label><b>Level: </b><label/>  
                        <select>
                            <option>-Please select a level-</option>
                            <option value='SSC'>SSC</option>
                            <option value='HSSC'>HSSC</option>
                            <option value='Diploma'>Diploma</option>
                            <option value='BE'>BE</option>
                            <option value='BTech'>BTech</option>
                            <option value='BCA'>BCA</option>
                            <option value='MCA'>MCA</option>
                        </select> 
                        <label><b>  Year</b><label/>   <input type='number' name='year' max='2020' min='2000'/> 
                        <label><b>Grade/%</b><label/>   <input type='text' name='grade'/>
                        <button type='button' onClick="removeEducation('education','${newdiv.className}')">Remove</button>`;
                    document.getElementById(divname).appendChild(newdiv);
                    counter++;
                    console.log(counter);
                    console.log(newdiv.className);
                }
            }


            function removeEducation(edudiv,divname) {
                console.log("deleted");
                document.getElementById(edudiv).removeChild(document.getElementsByClassName(divname)[0]);
                counter--;
            }
        </script>

        <!-- skills -->
        <p><b>Skills</b></p>
        <div id="skills">
            <label for="skillname"><b>Name</b></label>
            <input type="text" name="skillname">
            <label for="rating"><b>Rating:</b></label>
            <select name="rating" id="rating">
                <option>-Please select a rating-</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input name="addskill" type="button" value="Add Skill" onClick="addSkill('skills');"><br/>

        <script>

            var skillcounter = 1;
            var skilllimit = 3;
            function addSkill(divname1) {

                if (skillcounter == skilllimit) {
                    alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + skillcounter + " inputs");
                }
                else {
                    var snewdiv = document.createElement('div');
                    snewdiv.className="addskillclass"
                    snewdiv.innerHTML = "<label><b>Name</b></label>" + "<input type='text' name='skillname1'/>"+
                    "<label><b>Rating:</b></label>" + "<select><option>-Please select a rating-</option><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option><option value='6'>6</option><option value='7'>7</option><option value='8'>8</option><option value='9'>9</option><option value='10'>10</option></select>";
                    document.getElementById(divname1).append(snewdiv);
                    skillcounter++;
                    console.log(counter);
                }
            }


            // function removeSkill(divname1) {

            // }
        </script>

        <!-- hobby -->
        <br/>
        <label for="hobby"><b>Hobby</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your hobby" name="hobby"><br /><br />

        <!-- photourl -->
        <label for="photourl"><b>Photo</b></label>
        <input type="url" name="photourl" placeholder="photo url" /><br />

        <!-- submit -->
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />


    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Try this out. It worked. Made few changes to the remove function